# change dateedit2 value base on dateedit1

Tags: vb.net, winforms, date, devexpress

i want to ask, how does date value in dateedit2 auto update/value when i type or change the value in dateedit1 if the date exceed date "15". in dateedit2 enabled was false.
e.g if dateedit1 date is smaller than 15 then dateedit2.date change to 1 and if dateedit1 is larger than 15 then dateedit2.date change to 30 . what kind of event do i use in dateedit1

my code

```
 Private Sub DateEdit1_EditValueChanging(sender As Object, e As Controls.ChangingEventArgs) Handles DateEdit2.EditValueChanging
    Dim dat As Date = Date.FromOADate(15)
    If DateEdit1.DateTime.Date > dat Then
        DateEdit2.EditValue = Date.FromOADate(30)

    End If
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: 30 or the end of the month taken from dateedit1?

Comment: By the way, is this a control of type DateEdit from DevExpress?

Comment: @Steve just 30 not the end of the month, iam using devexpress

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly then you need to check what is the value of the day in your first DateEdit control and then define the new value for the second DateEdit control.

```
Private Sub DateEdit1_EditValueChanging(sender As Object, e As Controls.ChangingEventArgs) Handles DateEdit2.EditValueChanging
    Dim day As Integer
    Dim curDay As Integer = DateEdit1.DateTime.Day
    If curDay < 15 Then
        day = 1
    Else
        day = 30 ' DateTime.DaysInMonth(DateEdit1.DateTime.Year, DateEdit1.DateTime.Month)
    End If
    DateEdit2.DateTime = New DateTime(DateEdit1.Year, DateEdit1.Month, day)
End Sub
```

This of course requires the SyncSelectionWithEditValue enabled as you can read from the [DevExpress](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraEditorsDateEdit_EditValuetopic) documentation

While this follows your requirement to have always 30 as the value for the second datetime control I think that you need to check anyway for the month part because in case of february you will get an invalid date.

```
....
If curDay < 15 Then
    day = 1
Else
    ' For February we need an extra check....
    if DateEdit1.DateTime.Month = 2 Then
        day = DateTime.DaysInMonth(DateEdit1.DateTime.Year, 2)
    Else
        day = 30 
    End If
End If
.....
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this | I don't have `Dateedit` so I am using `DateTimePicker`

```
Private Sub DateTimePicker1_ValueChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles DateTimePicker1.ValueChanged
    DateTimePicker2.Value = DateTimePicker1.Value.AddDays(15)
End Sub
```